# SQL grouping on time interval

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a data set which is based on a timestamp. The Data set present record on every shut down occurrence in a 5 minute time interval. If a shut down occurred in the specific 5 min, then the record is added else no record. Thus no record means system has recovered

```
     Date          
07-Jul-15 12:05:00 
07-Jul-15 12:10:00
07-Jul-15 12:15:00
07-Jul-15 12:35:00
07-Jul-15 12:40:00
07-Jul-15 12:45:00
07-Jul-15 12:50:00
07-Jul-15 13:05:00
07-Jul-15 13:10:00
07-Jul-15 13:15:00
```

I would like to query and return

> 1.Number of shutdowns: The Number of shut down in this case is 3 based on between
>
> ```
> 12:15 to 12:35 
> 12:50 to 13:05
> ```

The system recovered

> 2. Period Between every shut down
>
> Example:
>
> 1.From: 07-Jul-15 12:05:00 To: 07-Jul-15 12:15:00 Duration : 15 Mins
>
> 2.From: 07-Jul-15 12:35:00 To: 07-Jul-15 12:50:00 Duration : 20 Mins

There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31283483/sql-oracle-counting-clusters/31284645) Question although a very different solution is required for this one.

would appreciate a fiddle example

Comment: Look at your sample data. Can you tell which row is shutdown, which is recovery? No? And how do you think we should guess?

Comment: Giorgi, the system is live, this sample data only present the shut down on a 5 min interval.

Comment: So you say if there interval of 5 mins then the system is live? And when 15 mins then it is shutdown?

Comment: No, the trigger is set to check every 5 mins, if the system is on, do nothing. if the system if shut down then push a record on that time the system is off. Basically the status is always 1 here.

Comment: Then I can not get how are you splitting you test data to live and shutdowns

Comment: Can you read my comment? Every record represents a shut down of 5 minutes interval. The live is based on if there is not record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT "DATE",
         CASE WHEN LAG( "DATE" ) OVER ( ORDER BY "DATE" ) + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE = "DATE" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_changed_group
  FROM   TEST
), grps AS (
  SELECT "DATE",
         SUM( has_changed_group ) OVER ( ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS grp
  FROM   changes
)
SELECT MIN( "DATE" ) AS shutdown_start,
       MAX( "DATE" ) AS shutdown_end,
       MAX( "DATE" ) - MIN( "DATE" ) + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE AS shutdown_duration
FROM   grps
GROUP BY grp;
```

**Output:**

```
SHUTDOWN_START               SHUTDOWN_END                 SHUTDOWN_DURATION
---------------------------- ---------------------------- -----------------
07-JUL-15 12.05.00.000000000 07-JUL-15 12.15.00.000000000 0 0:15:0.0        
07-JUL-15 12.35.00.000000000 07-JUL-15 12.50.00.000000000 0 0:20:0.0        
07-JUL-15 13.05.00.000000000 07-JUL-15 13.15.00.000000000 0 0:15:0.0
```

**Edit - Multiple machines:**

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5be04/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST ( MACHINE_ID, "DATE" ) AS
          SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:05:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:10:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:15:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:35:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:40:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:45:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:50:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:05:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:10:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 1, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:15:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:35:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:40:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 12:45:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:00:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:05:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:10:00' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 2, TIMESTAMP '2015-07-07 13:15:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH changes AS (
  SELECT MACHINE_ID,
         "DATE",
         CASE WHEN LAG( "DATE" ) OVER ( PARTITION BY MACHINE_ID ORDER BY "DATE" ) + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE = "DATE" THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS has_changed_group
  FROM   TEST
), grps AS (
  SELECT MACHINE_ID,
         "DATE",
         SUM( has_changed_group ) OVER ( PARTITION BY MACHINE_ID ORDER BY "DATE" ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW ) AS grp
  FROM   changes
)
SELECT MACHINE_ID,
       TO_CHAR( MIN( "DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS shutdown_start,
       TO_CHAR( MAX( "DATE" ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ) AS shutdown_end,
       TO_CHAR( MAX( "DATE" ) - MIN( "DATE" ) + INTERVAL '5' MINUTE ) AS shutdown_duration
FROM   grps
GROUP BY MACHINE_ID, grp
ORDER BY 1,2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5be04/5/0)**:

```
| MACHINE_ID |      SHUTDOWN_START |        SHUTDOWN_END |             SHUTDOWN_DURATION |
|------------|---------------------|---------------------|-------------------------------|
|          1 | 2015-07-07 12:05:00 | 2015-07-07 12:15:00 | +000000000 00:15:00.000000000 |
|          1 | 2015-07-07 12:35:00 | 2015-07-07 12:50:00 | +000000000 00:20:00.000000000 |
|          1 | 2015-07-07 13:05:00 | 2015-07-07 13:15:00 | +000000000 00:15:00.000000000 |
|          2 | 2015-07-07 12:35:00 | 2015-07-07 12:45:00 | +000000000 00:15:00.000000000 |
|          2 | 2015-07-07 13:00:00 | 2015-07-07 13:15:00 | +000000000 00:20:00.000000000 |
```

Comment: @MarmiteBomber - not according to the OP's desired output: `From: 07-Jul-15 12:05:00 To: 07-Jul-15 12:15:00 Duration : 15 Mins` (and if you go through the data then it is live at 12:00 then shutdown at 12:05, 12:10 and 12:15 but back live at 12:20 then that is somewhere between 10 and 20 minutes shutdown - on average 15 minutes)

Comment: @MT0 In case is we had multiple machines and one column for the time, how could we group?

Comment: @szakwani Update added to partition by multiple machines.

Answer (score 0):

Solution using Tom Kyte's "carry down" technique:

```
with test1 as (
select mydate,
-- mark starting records in each group
case when NVL((mydate - lag(mydate) over (order by mydate))*24*60,10) > 5 
then row_number() over (order by mydate) end as group_id
from test),
test2 as (
select mydate,
-- propagate group_id to all records
LAST_VALUE(group_id IGNORE NULLS) over (order by mydate) as group_id
from test1) 
select  min(mydate) shutdown_from, max(mydate) shutdown_to
from test2
group by group_id;
```

**Output**

```
SHUTDOWN_FROM       SHUTDOWN_TO       
------------------- -------------------
07.07.0015 12:05:00 07.07.0015 12:15:00 
07.07.0015 12:35:00 07.07.0015 12:50:00 
07.07.0015 13:05:00 07.07.0015 13:15:00
```

Comment: of course you'll not always see interruptions recovered within 5 minutes.

Comment: I had tried this, the issue here is when we have a single 5 minute shut down. it will not be considered

Comment: Secondly, how do you get the time between the shut downs?

Comment: @szakwani use the same LAG function. I updated the select with last_shutdown_to.

Comment: @szakwani you shold not expect to see things that are *below* your measure precision. The polling interval should be related to your SLA and should be set to the highes tolerable inavailability interval.